# Python: For loops and lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop

**Given a list x=[-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]** **use a for loop to create a new list, y, that contains the value aSin(10a) for each value, a, in list x. Plot the results using plot(x,y).**

I have...

```
x=[-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for a in x:

print sin(a)*(10*a)
```

The code returns the correct sin values but I'm not sure how to get the values into a new list y..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you mentioned in the text that you want a*sin(10a), but you have different thing in the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `list comprehensions` here

```
>>> y = [sin(10*i)*(i) for i in x]
```

Comment: this is great. thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 x=[-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
 y=list()
 for a in x:
     y.append(sin(a)*(10*a))
```

Answer (score 1):

the following code works

```
x=[-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = [i*sin(10*i) for i in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x=[-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y=[]
for a in x:
    y.append(sin(a)*(10*a))
```

Should work but do try to learn python!!

Answer (score 0):

Try [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python):

```
y = [a * sin(10*a) for a in x]
```

Hope that helps.